# DnsQuery vs DnsQueryEx - Improve performance and usage or alternatives

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, dns

I am trying to use reverse dns lookup (antispam like spamhaus) for IPv4/6 on Windows. So far the results are more than disappointing.

My requirement would be:

- Ability to lookup both IPv4 and IPV6
- Use custom DNS servers like [1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1/), 1.0.0.1, 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2606:4700:4700::1001 (add more than 1)
- Acceptable performance for lookup

Here is what I found so far:

- [DnsQuery_A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsquery_a)/W is fast-ish, but does not support IPv6 DNS
- [DnsQueryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsqueryex) supports IPv6 DNS, but is slower than DnsQuery_A/W, at least in my tests using synchronous mode (I did notice significant faster performance using asynchronous mode, however I am unable to "wait" for it properly inside a loop for each IP)
- [GetAddrInfoExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexw) is just terrible in performance, so not even going to talk about it

And here are some results from iterating a simple vector of [73 IP blacklist](https://www.blacklistmaster.com/blacklists) DNS, under Release and default optimizations:

- DnsQuery_W: 11 seconds
- DnsQueryEx: 24 seconds

This test was repeated several times to ensure a rough timing. DnsQuery_W is the winner in any case, however this does not support IPv6 DNS. Furthermore, there is no documentation how to add more than 1 DNS into the array.

Of course, I do understand that DNS servers can reply sometimes slower; however 20 seconds is a long time... too long.

**Sample code DnsQuery_W:**

```
PDNS_RECORD pDnsRecord = { 0 };

// Calling function DnsQuery to query Host or PTR records 
DNS_STATUS status = DnsQuery_W(temp.c_str(), //Pointer to OwnerName. 
                    DNS_TYPE_A, //Type of the record to be queried.
                    DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE, // Bypasses the resolver cache on the lookup. 
                    pSrvList, //Contains DNS server IP address.
                    &pDnsRecord, //Resource record that contains the response.
                    NULL); //Reserved for future use.

if (status)
{
    wprintf(L"Failed to query the host record for %ws and the error is %ws \n", temp.c_str(), GetErrorMessage(status).c_str());
}
else
{
    wprintf(L"Found %ws in %ws and the error is %d \n", temp.c_str(), list.second.c_str(), status);

    // Free memory allocated for DNS records.
    DNS_FREE_TYPE freetype;
    freetype = DnsFreeRecordListDeep;
    DnsRecordListFree(pDnsRecord, freetype);
}
```

**Sample code DnsQueryEx:**

```
SOCKADDR_STORAGE SockAddr           = { 0 };
INT AddressLength                   = sizeof(SockAddr);
WSAStringToAddressW((PWSTR)L"1.1.1.1", AF_INET, NULL, (LPSOCKADDR)&SockAddr, &AddressLength);

DNS_ADDR_ARRAY DnsServerList        = { 0 };
DnsServerList.MaxCount              = 1;
DnsServerList.AddrCount             = 1;
CopyMemory(DnsServerList.AddrArray[0].MaxSa, &SockAddr, DNS_ADDR_MAX_SOCKADDR_LENGTH);

PDNS_QUERY_CONTEXT pDnsQueryContext = NULL;
pDnsQueryContext                    = (PDNS_QUERY_CONTEXT)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(DNS_QUERY_CONTEXT));

if (NULL == pDnsQueryContext) {
    std::wcout << L"HeapAlloc() failed with error: " << GetErrorMessage(GetLastError()).c_str();
    continue;
}

pDnsQueryContext->QueryType             = DNS_TYPE_A;
pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.Version   = DNS_QUERY_REQUEST_VERSION1;
pDnsQueryContext->Callback              = NULL;

DNS_QUERY_REQUEST DnsQueryRequest       = { 0 };
DnsQueryRequest.Version                 = DNS_QUERY_REQUEST_VERSION1;
DnsQueryRequest.QueryName               = temp.c_str();
DnsQueryRequest.QueryType               = pDnsQueryContext->QueryType;
DnsQueryRequest.QueryOptions            = DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE;
DnsQueryRequest.pDnsServerList          = &DnsServerList;
DnsQueryRequest.InterfaceIndex          = 0;
// By omitting the DNS_QUERY_COMPLETION_ROUTINE callback from the pQueryCompleteCallback member of this structure, DnsQueryEx is called synchronously.
DnsQueryRequest.pQueryCompletionCallback = NULL;
DnsQueryRequest.pQueryContext           = pDnsQueryContext;

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

DNS_STATUS DnsStatus = DnsQueryEx(&DnsQueryRequest, &pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult, &pDnsQueryContext->DnsCancelHandle);

auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::wcout << L"DnsStatus: " << DnsStatus << L" (" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << L"ms) -> " << GetErrorMessage(DnsStatus).c_str();

pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.QueryStatus = DnsStatus;

if (pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.QueryStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if (NULL != pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.pQueryRecords) {
        DnsRecordListFree(pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.pQueryRecords, DnsFreeRecordList);
    }
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, pDnsQueryContext);
    continue;
}

for (PDNS_RECORD p = pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.pQueryRecords; p; p = p->pNext)
{
    WCHAR ipAddress[128] = {0};

    switch (p->wType)
    {
        case DNS_TYPE_A:
        {
            IN_ADDR ipv4;
            ipv4.S_un.S_addr = p->Data.A.IpAddress;
            RtlIpv4AddressToStringW(&ipv4, ipAddress);
        }
        break;

        case DNS_TYPE_AAAA:
        {
            IN6_ADDR ipv6;
            memcpy(ipv6.u.Byte, p->Data.AAAA.Ip6Address.IP6Byte, sizeof(ipv6.u.Byte));
            RtlIpv6AddressToStringW(&ipv6, ipAddress);
        }
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
        
    std::wcout << L"Found IP: " << ipAddress << L" in DNS: " << temp.c_str() << std::endl;
}

DnsRecordListFree(pDnsQueryContext->QueryResult.pQueryRecords, DnsFreeRecordList);
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, pDnsQueryContext);
```

Can someone please advise on how to achieve my goal(s)?

I'm happy to use any C++ libraries like Boost, etc, if there is anything out of the box that works decently.

Also, I would be more than happy to use the async method of DnsQueryEx, if someone can show me how to "wait for each result" inside a vector loop.

**Much appreciated!**

Comment: I'm not seeing any significant difference in the performance between `DnsQuery()` and `DnsQueryEx()`, and I'm certainly not seeing anything close to the level of 10 seconds. I'm running both in a loop 100 times and each is taking roughly between 1.4 and 1.7 seconds total. I'm only querying 1.1.1.1, though, so perhaps the issue is with one of the other DNS servers or specific to your network.

Comment: @Luke That's odd. 1.1.1.1 is the fastest dns on the planet but still odd. Can you try with a reverse dns like REVERSED_IP.zen.spamhaus.org?

Comment: @Luke I just realised that... 1.4 seconds is quite a lot for a dns resolution?

Comment: That 1.4 seconds is for 100 DNS queries. Using zen.spamhaus.org is significantly slower, taking about 1.7 seconds for just 10 DNS queries.

Comment: Oops, disregard that. Test was being interfered with by my stupid VPN. Querying either 100 times takes on the order of 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @Luke That's very odd. I do not have any VPN installed, and the machine has 1 Gbps. What windows do you have? VS? c++? Maybe something causing this. 1.5 seconds for 100 times is amazing really.

Comment: It's almost surely something network related. I'd fire up WireShark and look at the timings of what is actually going out and coming in over the wire.

Comment: @Luke can you post your code for arguments sake? Also, any idea how to add multiple DNS servers to DnsQueryEx? Thanks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Wxy3X4aG

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested, here's my experience. I use DnsQuery_W, fast enough to do without asynchronous and not as complicated as DnsQueryEx. And you can very well specify more than one DNS server address and use IPv6 too. You certainly have Powershell installed. If you use ILSpy or .NET Reflector to look at the "dnslookup.dll" file in the installed modules, you'll find a nice example of how to use DnsQuery_W under "ResolveDnsName". It is the source code for the Powershell module "Resolve-DnsName". Extremely faster than GetHostEntry for reverse queries.

Here is a - not so short - summary. I use DnsQuery only for reverse queries, so this is a really stripped down sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class DnsQuerySample
{
    #region structs and enums

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct sockaddr_in
    {
        private ushort Family;
        private ushort sin6_port;
        private uint IP4Addr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
        private char[] zero;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct sockaddr_in6
    {
        internal ushort sin6_family;
        private ushort sin6_port;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte[] IP4Addr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 0x10)]
        public byte[] IP6Address;
        private uint sin6_scope_id;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct DnsAddr
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal sockaddr_in6 SockAddr;
        [FieldOffset(0x20)]
        internal uint SockAddrLength;
        [FieldOffset(0x24)]
        internal uint SubnetLength;
        [FieldOffset(40)]
        internal uint Flags;
        [FieldOffset(0x2c)]
        internal uint Status;
        [FieldOffset(0x30)]
        internal uint Priority;
        [FieldOffset(0x34)]
        internal uint Weight;
        [FieldOffset(0x38)]
        internal uint Tag;
        [FieldOffset(60)]
        internal uint PayloadSize;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DnsAddrArray
    {
        internal uint MaxCount;
        internal uint AddrCount;
        private uint Tag;
        internal ushort Family;
        private ushort Reserved;
        private uint Flags;
        private uint MatchFlag;
        private uint Reserved1;
        private uint Reserved2;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
        internal DnsAddr[] DnsAddr;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 120)]
    internal struct DnsExtraInfo
    {
        public uint Version;
        public uint Size;
        public IntPtr pNext;
        public uint ID;
        public uint Reserved;
        public IntPtr ServerList;
        public DnsExtraInfo(IPAddress[] DnsServers)
        {
            this = new DnsExtraInfo();
            this.ID = 10;
            this.Version = 0x80000001;
            this.pNext = IntPtr.Zero;
            DnsAddrArray structure = new DnsAddrArray
            {
                AddrCount = (uint)DnsServers.Length,
                MaxCount = 5,
                DnsAddr = new DnsAddr[5]
            };
            for (int i = 0; (i < DnsServers.Length) && (i < 5); i++)
            {
                structure.Family = (ushort)DnsServers[i].AddressFamily;
                structure.DnsAddr[i].SockAddr.sin6_family = (ushort)DnsServers[i].AddressFamily;
                if (DnsServers[i].AddressFamily == ((AddressFamily)((int)AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)))
                {
                    structure.DnsAddr[i].SockAddr.IP6Address = DnsServers[i].GetAddressBytes();
                    structure.DnsAddr[i].SockAddrLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<sockaddr_in6>();
                }
                else
                {
                    structure.DnsAddr[i].SockAddr.IP4Addr = DnsServers[i].GetAddressBytes();
                    structure.DnsAddr[i].SockAddrLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<sockaddr_in>();
                }
            }
            this.ServerList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<DnsAddrArray>());
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<DnsAddrArray>(structure, this.ServerList, false);
        }
    }

    internal enum RecordType : ushort
    {
        PTR = 12
    }

    internal enum QueryOptions : ulong
    {
        DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE = 0x00000008,    // Bypasses the resolver cache on the lookup.
        DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE = 0x00000040,   // Prevents the DNS query from consulting the HOSTS file.Windows 2000 Server and Windows 2000 Professional: This value is not supported.
        DNS_QUERY_NO_NETBT = 0x00000080,        // Prevents the DNS query from using NetBT for resolution.Windows 2000 Server and Windows 2000 Professional: This value is not supported.
        DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY = 0x00000100,       // Directs DNS to perform a query using the network only, bypassing local information.Windows 2000 Server and Windows 2000 Professional: This value is not supported.
        DNS_QUERY_MULTICAST_ONLY = 0x00000400,  // Prevents the query from using DNS and uses only Local Link Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR).Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 or later.: This value is supported.
        DNS_QUERY_NO_MULTICAST = 0x00000800,    // (opposite of DNS_QUERY_MULTICAST_ONLY)
        DNS_QUERY_TREAT_AS_FQDN = 0x00001000    // Prevents the DNS response from attaching suffixes to the submitted name in a name resolution process.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682082(v=vs.85).aspx
    /// These field offsets could be different depending on endianness and bitness
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DnsRecord
    {
        public IntPtr pNext;        // DnsRecord*
        public IntPtr pName;        // string
        public RecordType wType;
        public ushort wDataLength;
        public FlagsUnion Flags;
        public uint dwTtl;
        public uint dwReserved;     // maybe QuestionClass, alway be 1 (DNS_CLASS_INTERNET)
        public DataUnion Data;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct DataUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public DNS_PTR_DATA PTR, NS, CNAME, DNAME, MB, MD, MF, MG, MR;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public IntPtr pDataPtr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682080(v=vs.85).aspx
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DNS_PTR_DATA
    {
        public IntPtr pNameHost;    // string
        public string NameHost { get { return Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pNameHost); } }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct FlagsUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint DW;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public DnsRecordFlags S;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682084(v=vs.85).aspx
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DnsRecordFlags
    {
        internal uint data;

        // DWORD Section :2;
        public DnsSection Section
        {
            get { return (DnsSection)(data & 0x3u); }
            set { data = (data & ~0x3u) | (((uint)value) & 0x3u); }
        }

        // DWORD Delete :1;
        public uint Delete // Reserved. Do not use.
        {
            get { return (data >> 2) & 0x1u; }
            set { data = (data & ~(0x1u << 2)) | (value & 0x1u) << 2; }
        }

        // DWORD CharSet :2;
        public DnsCharset CharSet
        {
            get { return (DnsCharset)((data >> 3) & 0x3u); }
            set { data = (data & ~(0x3u << 3)) | (((uint)value) & 0x3u) << 3; }
        }

        // DWORD Unused :3;
        public uint Unused // Reserved. Do not use.
        {
            get { return (data >> 5) & 0x7u; }
            set { data = (data & ~(0x7u << 5)) | (value & 0x7u) << 5; }
        }

        // DWORD Reserved :24;
        public uint Reserved // Reserved. Do not use.
        {
            get { return (data >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFu; }
            set { data = (data & ~(0xFFFFFFu << 8)) | (value & 0xFFFFFFu) << 8; }
        }
    }

    internal enum DnsSection : uint
    {
        Question = 0,
        Answer = 1,
        Authority = 2,
        Additional = 3
    }

    internal enum DnsCharset : uint
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Unicode = 1,
        Utf8 = 2,
        Ansi = 3
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Call Win32 DNS API DnsQuery.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pszName">Host name.</param>
    /// <param name="wType">DNS Record type.</param>
    /// <param name="options">DNS Query options.</param>
    /// <param name="pExtra">Fka aipServers, now reserved but functional; IP4AddressArray or DnsExtraInfo, we use DnsExtraInfo.</param>
    /// <param name="ppQueryResults">Query results.</param>
    /// <param name="pReserved">Reserved argument.</param>
    /// <returns>WIN32 status code</returns>
    /// <remarks>For aipServers, DnqQuery expects either null or an array of one IPv4 address.</remarks>
    [DllImport("dnsapi", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int _DnsQueryW(
        [In] string pszName,
        [In] ushort wType,
        [In] uint options,
        [In][Out] ref DnsExtraInfo pExtra,
        [Out] out IntPtr ppQueryResults,
        [Out] IntPtr pReserved);

    internal static int DnsQuery(string pszName, RecordType wType, QueryOptions options, ref DnsExtraInfo pExtra, out IntPtr ppQueryResults)
    {
        return _DnsQueryW(pszName, (ushort)wType, (uint)options, ref pExtra, out ppQueryResults, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call Win32 DNS API DnsRecordListFree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pRecordList">DNS records pointer</param>
    /// <param name="FreeType">Record List Free type</param>
    [DllImport("dnsapi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "DnsRecordListFree", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void _DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, int FreeType);

    #endregion structs and enums

    internal static void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList)
    {
        _DnsRecordListFree(pRecordList, 0);
    }

    public static List<string> GetHostName(IPAddress iPAddress, IPAddress[] DNSServerAddresses)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        // Use DNS only, fastest queries with these options.
        QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE |
                               QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE |
                               QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_NO_MULTICAST |
                               QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_NO_NETBT |
                               QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_TREAT_AS_FQDN |
                               QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY;

        DnsExtraInfo pExtra = new DnsExtraInfo();

        if (DNSServerAddresses != null && DNSServerAddresses.Length != 0)
        {
            if (DNSServerAddresses.Length > 5)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("A maximum of 5 addresses are supported!", "DNSServerAddresses");
            }
            pExtra = new DnsExtraInfo(DNSServerAddresses);
        }

        var recordsArray = IntPtr.Zero;
        string reverse = ToReverseLookup(iPAddress);
        try
        {
            var result = DnsQuery(reverse,
                                  RecordType.PTR,
                                  options,
                                  ref pExtra,
                                  out recordsArray);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(result);
                throw new Win32Exception(result, iPAddress.ToString() + " : " + ex.Message);
            }

            DnsRecord record;
            var recordList = new List<string>();
            for (var recordPtr = recordsArray; !recordPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero); recordPtr = record.pNext)
            {
                record = (DnsRecord)Marshal.PtrToStructure(recordPtr, typeof(DnsRecord));
                if (record.wType == RecordType.PTR)
                {
                    recordList.Add(record.Data.PTR.NameHost);
                    //break; // one name is enough
                }
            }

            return recordList;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (recordsArray != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                DnsRecordListFree(recordsArray);
            }
            if (pExtra.ServerList != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pExtra.ServerList);
                pExtra.ServerList = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static string ToReverseLookup(IPAddress iPAddress)
    {
        string text = iPAddress.ToString();
        if (iPAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            string[] array = text.Split(new char[1] { '.' });
            text = array[3] + "." + array[2] + "." + array[1] + "." + array[0] + ".in-addr.arpa";
        }
        else
        {
            if (iPAddress.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            text = "ip6.arpa";
            byte[] addressBytes = iPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
            foreach (byte num in addressBytes)
            {
                byte b = (byte)(num & 0xFu);
                byte b2 = (byte)((num & 0xF0) >> 4);
                text = string.Format("{0:X}.{1:X}.{2}", b, b2, text);
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

    public DnsQuerySample()
    { }
}
```

You can use it with:

```
IPAddress[] servers =
{
    IPAddress.Parse("1.1.1.1"),
    IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"),
    IPAddress.Parse("2606:4700:4700::1111"),
    IPAddress.Parse("2001:4860:4860::8888")
};

IPAddress search = IPAddress.Parse("2a02:2e0:3fe:1001:302::");

var ret = DnsQuerySample.GetHostName(search, servers);
foreach (var name in ret)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

With Wireshark or a firewall you can see that it works with IPv6 and that DnsQuery uses the server addresses. I don't know if the restriction to 5 addresses is stored in DnsQuery. Maybe you can increase the number if you adjust the structures accordingly. Have fun!